# Wifi connection unstable using Belkin USB dongle on 17.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I started on Elementary OS, then moved to Ubuntu 16 LTS and now I am on Ubuntu 17.04. Using a Belkin Wifi USB dongle, the connection drops regularly on all OSs with my hardware. The only solution is either to remove and re-insert the dongle or to disconnect and reconnect to the network. I already tried a few other answers here on Ask Ubuntu but none of them worked. Like disabling mac address randomisation and updating to the latest version.

Here is some system info.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:5608 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 6080:8060  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 050d:1102 Belkin Components F7D1102 N150/Surf 
Micro Wireless Adapter v1000 [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers (rev 36)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 36)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 36)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-
E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)
```

**UPDATE**

Additional Wifi info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 03 Nov 2017 10:57 CET +0100

Booted last: 03 Nov 2017 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-38-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 13:24:27 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:5608 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 6080:8060  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 050d:1102 Belkin Components F7D1102 N150/Surf Micro Wireless Adapter v1000 [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

snd_soc_rt5651         90112  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5651
rtl8xxxu              126976  0
rtl8192cu              65536  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        49152  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                73728  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              782336  4 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu,rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_soc_core          233472  2 snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_soc_rt5651
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_rt5651

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.15.100/24 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global dynamic wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
       valid_lft 86310sec preferred_lft 86310sec
    inet6 fe80::e911:6e7c:e7cf:52e3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"QUANTIS"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'QUANTIS' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:13   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.15.1 dev wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]> scope link metric 1000 
192.168.15.0/24 dev wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.15.100 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       794     1  0 10:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        802.11n WLAN Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8192cu
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.10.0-38-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     QUANTIS
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       0300df10-cf62-48ea-896c-3aee751a7001
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     150 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   0300df10-cf62-48ea-896c-3aee751a7001 | QUANTIS
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.15.100/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.15.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1509789354
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.15.100
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.15.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.15.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.15.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.15.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e911:6e7c:e7cf:52e3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

SSID     BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
QUANTIS  <MAC 'QUANTIS' [AC1]>  Infra  3     2422 MHz  54 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/QUANTIS]] (600 root)
[connection] id=QUANTIS | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=QUANTIS
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Madrid (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)

wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'QUANTIS' [AC1]>
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"QUANTIS"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000027f1aacf
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8xxxu]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/rtl8xxxu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_bt.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B_NoBT.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723aufw_A.bin
license:        GPL
description:    RTL8XXXu USB mac80211 Wireless LAN Driver
author:         Jes Sorensen <Jes.Sorensen@redhat.com>
srcversion:     4579E6203C3D3D3D7D7B53E
depends:        mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           debug:Set debug mask (int)
parm:           ht40_2g:Enable HT40 support on the 2.4GHz band (bool)
parm:           dma_aggregation:Enable DMA packet aggregation (bool)
parm:           dma_agg_timeout:Set DMA aggregation timeout (range 1-127) (int)
parm:           dma_agg_pages:Set DMA aggregation pages (range 1-127, 0 to disable) (int)

[rtl8192cu]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n USB wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
srcversion:     72438BA624FED2B5E5FCBF6
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi,rtl8192c-common,rtl_usb
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl_usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_usb.ko
description:    USB basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     4BD8945CF1E356CE23926B3
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rtl8192c_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     137A358D6D5739FE3E9DA67
depends:        rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     884DE3F31278351A45DA409
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     309C9ACED540FCAA1DE7422
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-38-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/debug: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_agg_pages: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_aggregation: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/dma_agg_timeout: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/rtl8xxxu/parameters/ht40_2g: Permission denied
[rtl8xxxu]

[rtl8192cu]
debug: 0
swenc: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    5.042384] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[    5.097096] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[    5.097202] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[    5.097314] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[    5.109665] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    5.785288] rtl8192cu 1-1:1.0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from wlan0
[    8.163576] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link is not ready
[    8.166813] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[    8.182147] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[    8.575249] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   10.644121] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: authenticate with <MAC 'QUANTIS' [AC1]>
[   10.668908] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: send auth to <MAC 'QUANTIS' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   10.691602] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: authenticated
[   10.696077] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: associate with <MAC 'QUANTIS' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   10.705513] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'QUANTIS' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[   10.706837] wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: associated
[   10.707030] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling power management? Check if it's enabled with `iwconfig`. Also, to avoid endless back and forth soliciting more info, check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: I updated the answer with the Wifi data. Power management seems to be off: `Power Management:off`

Comment: At your router change the wireless encryption settings to WPA2-AES. Always avoid mixed modes and especially TKIP. Also be realistic about your hardware capabilities: You're using an old b/g only router.

Comment: And your wireless script results show that you're using **17.04**, not 17.10. support for 17.04 will end in a few months.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the router. Also, none of my other devices (MacBook, iMac, iPad, iPhones) are experiencing any issues.

Comment: Updating to 17.10 as we speak.

Comment: *none of my other devices  are experiencing any issues* means nothing. Whbat I commented above is 1. the experts' recommendations for wireless encryption *always, everywhere and irrespective of the clients' OSes* and 2. certain devices running with Linux drivers are quite picky about it (for a reason, read #1). It may not have a solution except the one mentioned above that must be implemented at the network level.

Comment: Updating to 17.10 solved a lot of issues. Suddenly the built-in Wifi started working, so the USB dongle is no longer necessary. Also, the Wifi connection no longer drops. I've been surfing for an hour now without a single interruption. And as the cherry on the cake, I got the battery level indicator working, I can safely close and open the laptop as many times as I want, without having to reboot it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 solved the Wifi problem as well as a lot of other issues. Now I no longer need the dongle as the built-in Wifi is working as it should. Both the dongle and the built-in Wifi work flawlessly.